# How to model data flows with a SQL backend?

Tags: sql, sql-server, workflow, backend, workflow-engine

My question is not about a specific code. I am trying to automate a business data governance data flow using a SQL backend. I have put a lot of time searching the internet or reaching out people for the right direction, but unfortunately I have not yet found something promising so I have a lot of hope I would find some people here to save from a big headache.

Assume that we have a flow (semi static/dynamic flow) for our business process. We have different departments owning portions of data. we need to take different actions during the flow such as data entry, data validation, data exportation, approvals, rejections, notes etc and also automatically define deadlines, create reports of overdue tasks and people accountable for them etc.

I guess the data management part would not be extremely difficult, but how to write an application (codes) to run the flow (workflow engine) is where I struggle. Should I use triggers or should I choose to write codes to frequently run queries to push the completed steps to next step, how I can use SQL tables to keep the track of flow etc

If one could give me some hints on this matter, I would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the sql server integration services SSIS, you can easily mange the scripts and workflow based on some lookup selections, and also you can schedule SSIS package on timely bases to trigger and do the job.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard task to implement application server on sql server. Also it's will be very vendor depended solution. Best way i think to use sql server as data storage and some application server for business logic over data storage.

Comment: what would be your choice if you were free to choose anything you wanted?

Comment: In my tasks i prefer PHP (with Symfony framework for example for you) and MySQL InnoDB. I like PHP for for big functions and libs pack and like MySQL for stability. But a think you can use any open workflow framework for you task. May be  good idea to select  BPMN compatible, but not sure about it.  Any case i propose you to research workflow systems market and proposals. It's will be more effective and low cost way.